# Need to search for number combinations within textbox(c#)

Tags: c#, numbers

I have a form with a text box which accepts 12 Numbers as input.

I want to be able to search for 2 digit, 3 digit, 4 digit and 5 digit combinations and show predefined outputs for each such combination found.

Example

Text entered in textbox  : `919982115672`

Outputs

```
8211 : Some predefined text
82 : Some predefined text
9821 : Some predefined text
5672 : Some predefined text
```

And so on

Also some suggestions on how can i make a database of predefined values would be awesome

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you got so far and what didn't worked for you.

Comment: I think you should check [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  SO is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. Questions that ask for a specific programming problem are in scope. Questions that ask for code or tutorials are out of scope and quickly closed or downvoted. The same hold for vague or broad questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string Input = "919982115672";
Console.Write(Search(Input));


public string Search(string Input)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> PreDefinedSearchAndTexts = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    PreDefinedSearchAndTexts.Add("8211", "Hello");
    PreDefinedSearchAndTexts.Add("82", "My name is inigo montya");
    PreDefinedSearchAndTexts.Add("9821", "You killed my father");
    PreDefinedSearchAndTexts.Add("5672", "Prepare to die");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    foreach(string Key in PreDefinedSearchAndTexts.Keys) 
    {
        if(Input.Contains(Key))
        {
            sb.Append(Key).Append(" : ").AppendLine(PreDefinedSearchAndTexts[Key]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Results:

```
8211 : Hello
82 : My name is inigo montya
9821 : You killed my father
5672 : Prepare to die
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked for me.

Apologies if my question was vague I'll try to be more specific next time around

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for substring, like here:

```
string text = "919982115672";
Dictionary<string, string> combiTexts = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{ 
    {"8211","Some predefined text"},
    {"82","Some predefined text"},
    {"9821","Some predefined text"},
    {"5672","Some predefined text"}
};
var matchingSubstrings = text.getAllSubstrings()
    .Where(combiTexts.ContainsKey)
    .Select(str => string.Format("{0} : {1}", str, combiTexts[str]));
```

Used this extension to extract all substrings from a string:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> getAllSubstrings(this string word)
{
    return from charIndex1 in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length)
           from charIndex2 in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length - charIndex1 + 1)
           where charIndex2 > 0
           select word.Substring(charIndex1, charIndex2);
}
```

Output

```
foreach(string output in matchingSubstrings)
    Console.WriteLine(output);

9821 : Some predefined text
82 : Some predefined text
8211 : Some predefined text
5672 : Some predefined text
```

Answer (score 0):

On the textbox changed event simply compare the text in the textbox with the predefined strings that you want to search (so for every number the user adds, your program will check on the spot if any combinations were found)